# Error trying to install eblearn on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, neural-network, linker-errors, failed-installation

I have been trying to install eblearn since two days. I followed the installation guideliness given on the eblearn website(http://eblearn.sourceforge.net/install.html#quick_install_for_core)
When I reach the step 2 of Quick install for core and tools, it gives me the following error:

/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lPTHREAD_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND/libpthread.so
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Kindly help me solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem,
i first updated my ubuntu and it worked.
Command :**sudo apt-get update**